# Changing date column organisation in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has in one row, a variable, a start date, and end date, and a unique ID :

```
ID    Start    End       Var
521   12/1/14  20/1/14   46
212   2/4/13   4/4/13    91
541   17/3/14  21/3/14   76
729   11/8/14  14/8/14   232
```

e.tc...

I would like to convert it to a more traditional form, suitable for instance to input into an lm style function i.e

```
Date     ID    Var  
12/1/14  521   23
19/1/14  521   23
......

26/3/14  541   76
```

e.t.c....

The main challenge is to average the Var has been averaged across the corresponding dates, the ID column could possibly be used to do this but I do not know how.

Has anyone done this before, know of a way to do this or think its impossible?

Comment: I think I'm going to make a daily date bridge for the range of dates, put a value that occurred for the entire duration as demarcated by Start and End on that day, divide those values by the day length of the period, then aggregate by week. 
Will post the solution once I have written it.

Answer (score 2):

To get the difference in term of days, you first have to convert both `Start` and `End` to a date format with `POSIXct`. Then you can convert to weeks with a division by 7.
Which gives (assuming `dd` is your data.frame) :

```
dd$Start = as.POSIXct(cc, format="%d/%m/%y")
dd$End = as.POSIXct(cc, format="%d/%m/%y")
dd$Ellapsed = as.numeric(dd$End - dd$Start) / 7
dd$Var = dd$Var / dd$Ellapsed
dd = dd[c("Ellapsed", "ID", "Var")]
```

Comment: Sorry I put the date separation in as periods by accident, the dates in Start and End are already formatted as PosixCt.

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with dates in an `lm` one way is to convert the dates into `as.POSIXct` type first:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='ID    Start    End       Var
521   12.1.14  14.1.14   47
212   2.4.13   4.4.13    91
541   17.3.14  21.3.14   76
729   11.8.14  14.8.14   232')
```

**Solution**

For example, for using Start only in the model:

```
df$Start <- as.POSIXct(df$Start, format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

**Output**

```
> lm(Var ~ Start, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = Var ~ Start, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        Start  
  1.597e+05    2.585e-06
```

Another way would be to use the `zoo` package which specialises in time series.

In order to work with dates in an `lm` one way is to convert the dates into `as.POSIXct` type first:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='ID    Start    End       Var
521   12.1.14  14.1.14   47
212   2.4.13   4.4.13    91
541   17.3.14  21.3.14   76
729   11.8.14  14.8.14   232')
```

**Solution**

For example, for using Start only in the model:

```
df$Start <- as.POSIXct(df$Start, format='%d.%m.%y')
```

**Output**

```
> lm(Var ~ Start, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = Var ~ Start, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        Start  
  1.597e+05    2.585e-06
```

Another way would be to use the `zoo` package which specialises in time series.

**Edit**

So you need to average by weeks. Then you can do the following:

```
#These need to be POSIXct
df$Start <- as.POSIXct(df$Start, format='%d.%m.%y')
df$End   <- as.POSIXct(df$End, format='%d.%m.%y')

#calculate the difference of start and End Dates in weeks
df$diff  <- as.numeric((df$End - df$Start)/7) 

#divide Var by the diff column calculated above
df$averaged_var <- df$Var / df$diff
```

Run the regression as you want using `averaged_var` from above.

Comment: This would assign the Var to the wrong dates, the periods between Start and End are variable.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand how you would calculate `Var`. In your output, the value under the `Var` column seems to be the same... Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: So if Var had a value of 50, and the time between Start and End was two weeks, then in the output frame's Var would take a value of 25 for those two weeks.

Comment: this would change the values but it does not fix the problem of allocating to the correct dates.